# BIBO stability of $1/x(t)$

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems, homework

I realize this is quite basic stuff but I am having trouble with the following question:

> Determine whether the following system with input $x(t)$ and output $y(t)$ is BIBO stable: $$y(t) = \frac{1}{x(t)}$$

My intuition says that it is not stable, just from thinking about the case where $x(t) = 0$. However, this would result in $y(t)$ being undefined, not going to infinity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** define a bound for $|x(t)|$, i.e., $|x(t)|\le A$; now try to find a positive number $B$ such that $|y(t)|\le B$ for any $|x(t)|\le A$ (that's simply the definition of BIBO stability). For the system $y(t)=1/x(t)$ it should be easy to show that the above cannot be satisfied (because $|x(t)|$ can get arbitrarily small).

Comment: Assume it's true : then $|x(t)| \geq 1/B$ which does not hold at all cases. Is that enough?

Comment: @tonythestark: Yes, for $|y(t)|$ to be bounded by $B$, $x(t)$ would need to satisfy $|x(t)|\ge 1/B$, which is no upper bound.